# What is considered an error in the sustained attention to response task (SART)?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, experimental-psychology, attention

The traditional SART task requires key presses to all digits appearing on the screen. However, the key press should be withheld if the digit is a 3

When aggregating the collected data, what is considered an error?

Is it simply the number of times the key was pressed when a 3 is on the screen? Or does it also include incorrectly withheld key presses (i.e. when the digit is anything other than 3)?

Answer (score 2):

Both are errors indeed. Pressing when a 3 is shown is called a false alarm, and not pressing when a three is shown is a miss. Correct responses are (1) hits (pressing when anything but a three is shown) or (2) correct rejections (not pressing with a three).

[image: http://gregstevens.com/2012/06/28/minimum-wage-part-2-signal-detection-theory/]

These classifications are used in [signal detection theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detection_theory) (Wiki). More specifically, they are used to calculate [sensitivity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_index) and bias.

Sensitivity, or d-prime (see also other questions on CogSci, e.g. [Calculating d-prime](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/9282/11318)), is the metric for how well one can distinguish targets from distractors. Bias, on the other hand, is:

> the extent to which one response is more probable than another ([Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detection_theory))

Comment: I realise that they're both errors, but are they both used in the error calculation that is typically published? The original Robertson paper isn't explicit about this, but I get the sense they are only considering false alarms in their results

Comment: I made some minor changes to my answer in hope to clarify my answer. I don't work with it myself, so I don't know of any recent literature and their practices, but I hope my answer may give you some starting point for your search.